# Get rid of space in a date

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

When i define my date the output contain spaces:

```
set thedateis=20/10/2017
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %thedateis%') do set day=%%a & set month=%%b & set year=%%c
echo The chosen date is: %thedateis%, Day:.%day%., Month:.%month%., Year:.%year%.
```

it gives me

```
The chosen date is: 20/10/2017, Day:.20 ., Month:.10 ., Year:.2017.
```

How can I get rid of the spaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you added the spaces yourself and did not isolate your strings from your ampersands.

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/" %%A In ("%thedateis%") Do Set "day=%%A"&Set "month=%%B"&Set "year=%%C"
```

**Edit**

You need to learn to use the best practice notation of:

```bat
Set "variableName=variableValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (thanks to @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ) and it works very well:

```
set thedateis=11/12/2017
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %thedateis%') do (
    set day=%%a
    set month=%%b
    set year=%%c
    )
echo The chosen date is: %thedateis%, Day:.%day%., Month:.%month%., Year:.%year%.
```

Comment: You need to still learn best practice and use the following notation: `Set "thedateis=11/12/2017"`, `Set "day=%%a"`, `Set "month=%%b"` and `Set "year=%%c"`.